# Routing public internet access through AWS direct connect

Tags: amazon-web-services, networking

I have AWS direct connect connections in regions A and B both connected to VPCs via private virtual interfaces. I have been able to connect EC2 instances in regions A and B via private IP addresses over the direct connection.

How can I set up my networking so that when I access a specific public IP range(not necessarily an AWS service) from an EC2 instance in my VPC in region A that the request gets routed through the direct connection to region B and then goes into the public internet in region B?

Many thanks

Comment: Could you explain the reason for doing this instead of using the Internet GW in Region A?
What about creating a route in the router attached to your VPC in Region A to route the traffic to the specific public IP range to the Virtual Private Gateway, which is attached to the Direct Connect GW? You might need to also manipulate the route table in Region B to redirect incoming traffic coming from Region B to Region B internet GW?

Comment: Hi Romain. Thanks for the answer. The reason is latency. We need to connect to a service that is publicly hosted on AWS in Region B from a server in region A with low latency. Routing the specific public IP Range to the Virtual Gateway has not worked so far ( I don't know why).

Comment: hard to troubleshoot without looking at all the route tables, Wireshark, traceroute output etc... If the problem is latency, have you looked into any NaaS solution like PacketFabric, Megaport, or similar? You can connect your AWS regions via public BGP peering through the partner network which usually offers low latency. Maybe something to explore. Keep us up to date on your finding/solution anyway!